# Return boolian in parent function after child promise resolves

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am working in a framework that **requires** the parent function to return `true` or `false`. Within that function, I'd like to run an async operation.

How do I make the parent function return `true` or `false` after an async action?

Example of what doesn't work:

```js
   function parent() {
     const child = new Promise();
     child.then(
       function (success) { return true },
     )
   }
```

The problem is that returning is happining within the context of the child.then() function.

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous call.

Answer (score -1):

This necessarily requires that the parent function be async as well, unless you want to block the main thread, which would be considered an anti-pattern.

Do this:

```
const parent = async () => {
    const childResponse = await child();
    if (childResponse === "something") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Do NOT do this:

```
const parent = () => {
    let promiseResult, parentReturnValue;

    child.then(result => {
        promiseResult = result;
        if (promiseResult === "something") {
            parentReturnValue = true;
        } else {
            parentReturnValue = false;
        }
    });

    while (promiseResult === undefined) {
        // block the main thread
    }
    
    return parentReturnValue;
};
```